std::memcpy from an object to another one of same type through an intermediate array of bytes
This is a follow up of Bitwise swapping the internal representation of two simple objects, even if they are not of a trivially copyable type.
I merely simplify a bit OP snippet and make the considered type trivially copyable:
#include<cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

struct SimpleClass {};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<SimpleClass>);
    SimpleClass s1;
    SimpleClass s2;

    constexpr size_t SimpleClass_SIZE = sizeof(SimpleClass);
    alignas(SimpleClass) char tmp[SimpleClass_SIZE];
    std::memcpy(&tmp, &s1, SimpleClass_SIZE);
    // next line is OK under https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-2
    // std::memcpy(&s1, &tmp, SimpleClass_SIZE);
    // does https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-2 apply (not the original object)
    std::memcpy(&s2, &tmp, SimpleClass_SIZE);
}

Obviously the intermediate array is useless but the original post was about swapping both objects value representations, thus the intermediate storage.
During the ensuing discussion, the consensus was that the code was valid under https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-3.
Yet https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#general-2:

For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up the object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte ([cstddef.syn]).27 If the content of that array is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original value.

(emphasis mine)
It guarantees that you can copy back to the same object but not to a different one.
I think that the spirit would be to copy back into an object of same type but not necessarily the original one.
IMHO, all compiler consider this construct as correct, which is meaningful.
Is it a ill-wording of the standard, is there another item for this situation or is it formally UB so far?

I don't think #2 limits #3 regarding source of underlying bytes. #3 doesn't say that you obtained underlying bytes from a specific source, it only says that you have underlying bytes making s1 (somewhere, somehow). Source of these bytes can be an array, because #2 allows copying underlying bytes into an array.

@Yksisarvinen: A common sequence of events is that (1) the authors of the C or C++ Standard will fail to explicitly define a particular corner case case because they don't see any ambiguity about how a compiler that is making a good faith effort to behave usefully would process it; (2) some compiler writers will code their optimizers in a manner incompatible with that corner case; (3) rather than fix their optimizers, those compiler writers will block any effort to codify the expectations of the earlier standard's authors.

Yes, #3 specifically says this is OK. The bytes of s1 are copied into s2 through an intermediate array.

@supercat so cynical... C++ standards committee is not monolithic. If they didn't standardize the behavior, it is almost guaranteed that (1) there is not a consensus among committee members how it should behave and (2) the compiler writers are among the committee members and choose one of the possible meanings and (3) then there's divergence between implementations or intent... and resolving that is hard. The people in 1 and 2 overlap and 2 are acting in good faith.

@JeffGarrett: The maintainers of gcc and clang willfully ignore the intentions of the authors of C89 and C99 documented in the published Rationale documents, and deliberately mischaracterize the C++ Standard as defining conformance criteria for programs despite the fact that it explicitly says it does not do so.  They do not act in good faith to efficiently process the language the C Standard was chartered to define, and I see no reason to believe they act in any better faith with regard to C++.

@JeffGarrett: If everyone were acting in good faith, there should be no difficulty recognizing the existence of implementations that process certain corner cases meaningfully, others that don't, and predefined macros or intrinsics to distinguish them.  Acknowledging support for useful corner cases as a quality-of-implementation issue, however, would make clang and gcc look bad compared with other compilers that can support those corner cases without having to disable optimizations wholesale.
